# Observable.zip issues

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, observable

I download posts from two pages from Facebook using Retrofit and RxJava. I want to download them by Observable.zip but I'm getting `onError :  An operation is not implemented: not implemented`.

My code:

```
    var fb1 = dataManager.getPosts(ApplicationConstants.FACEBOOK_PAGE_1, ApplicationConstants.FACEBOOK_APP_TOKEN, "70")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())


    var fb2 = dataManager.getPosts(ApplicationConstants.FACEBOOK_PAGE_2, ApplicationConstants.FACEBOOK_APP_TOKEN, "70")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

val observableZip : Observable<PostList> = Observable.zip(fb1,fb2, object: Function<PostList, PostList>, BiFunction<PostList, PostList, PostList> {
            override fun apply(t: PostList): PostList {
            }


            override fun apply(t1: PostList, t2: PostList): PostList {
            }

        })

        compositeDisposable.add(observableZip.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
                {result -> posts.addAll(result.data)},
                {t : Throwable? -> Log.d("TAG",t?.message) },
                {view.setAdapter(posts)
                view.hideProgressBar()}
        ))
```

I not exactly understend how to make Observable.zip as examples in the Internet are not clearly explained.

**Q:** How to change my code to make Observable.zip working ?

Comment: Can you include full stack trace of error

Comment: It throws error in `observableZip` : `D/TAG: An operation is not implemented: not implemented`

Comment: Try replacing your fb1 and fb2 variables with functions which return an observable.

Comment: Try subscribing to `fb1` only and see what it produces. Also please post what `t.printStackTrace()` prints instead of what `Log.d` produces.

Comment: @akarnokd if droho would subscribe, `fb1` and `fb2` would be `Disposables`, so there would be nothing to `zip`...

Comment: With incomplete questions and no stacktrace, one can only speculate where odd errors come. I suggested fb1 running standalone to rule out the error comes from the facebook API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `zip` should look like this:

```
val observableZip : Observable<PostList> = Observable.zip(fb1,fb2, object : BiFunction<PostList, StriPostList, PostList> {
        override fun apply(t1: PostList, t2: PostList): PostList {
           // do the zipping
        }
    })
```

1. There is no `zip` with parameters of type `Function`, *and* `BiFunction`. Only the list of observables and then a `BiFunction` (or, alternatively a single `ObservableSource` and a normal `Function`)
2. It's important to use the `BiFunction` from Rx, so make sure you're using `import io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction` *not* `java.util.function.BiFunction`

Comment: Thanks ! Your solution works for me. I would give you vote up but I dont have enought repo now